# Relations between minimal free resolution of a module and minimal free resolution of its submodule

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, $I\subset J$ be two ideals. What can we say about the minimal free resolutions of $R/I$ and $R/J$? Is one necessarily a subcomplex of the other?

Comment: There is of course a map of complexes. But if you meant that one is a subcomplex in the sense that all the maps are inclusions, the answer is no.

Comment: @Mohan What are the maps between complexes given by? I think the first map would be inclusion and the others are maps that make the diagram commute, right? Also, conversely if there is a map of complexes does that mean $I\subset J$? Thanks!